# S3 Client Creation with AWS SDK for Java 2.X

Tags: java, amazon-s3, java-8, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have an existing functionality where I create S3 client object from encrypted credentials and region in AWS SDK version 1.12.435. Now, I have to upgrade the entire code base to AWS SDK for Java 2 version(2.20.32). I am not seeing an equivalent class for the client credential or transfer manager. Following is my S3 client object creation function in version 1.X

```
public AmazonS3 getS3Client(final String s3AK, final String s3SK, final String s3Url, String region) throws Exception {         
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(EncryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(s3AK), EncryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(s3SK))); 
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true).withCredentials(credentialsProvider).withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s3Url, region)).build();        
        return s3Client;
}
```

Let me know how I could replace this way of S3 client creation to an equivalent way in AWS SDK for java 2.X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent is something like below.

The transfer manager is in a separate maven package `software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager`.

In the 1.x SDK a lot of classes were `AWS*`, in 2.x it's now `Aws*` which is sometimes annoyingly subtle.

```java
public S3AsyncClient getS3Client(final String s3AK, final String s3SK, final String s3Url, String region) throws Exception {
    AwsCredentials creds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(EncryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(s3AK), EncryptDecryptUtils.decrypt(s3SK));
    AwsCredentialsProvider provider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(creds);

    S3EndpointParams endpointParams = S3EndpointParams.builder()
        .endpoint(s3Url)
        .region(Region.of(region))
        // path style access is done by default if the url is not a
        // virtual host IIRC, if not you can force path style with
        // .forcePathStyle(true) // I think you only need this once here or in the client
        .build();

    Endpoint endpoint = S3EndpointProvider
        .defaultProvider()
        .resolveEndpoint(endpointParams.build()).join();

    S3AsyncClient s3Client = S3AsyncClient
        .builder()
        .credentialsProvider(awsCreds)
        .endpointOverride(endpoint.url())
        // path style access is done by default if the url is not a
        // virtual host IIRC, if not you can force path style with
        // .forcePathStyle(true) // I think you only need this once here or in the params
        .build();
    return s3Client;
}
```

Comment: This works. I have updated the transfer manager as well, using the new package and pom entry.